# Saving Sequential data in Java

Tags: java, android

I have some problems about saving sequential data (Contour Area), I have a project that detect contour. And I want to save data contour area in my android. I already save that contour area in file, but its just the last one, not a sequential data(all contour area) .
here's my contour code:

```
Imgproc.findContours(mDilated, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
int a =15;
float b = (float)4.55;
double maxVal = 0;
int maxValIdx = 0;
for ( int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++ ) {
    double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
    if (maxVal < contourArea) {
        maxVal = contourArea;
        maxValIdx = contourIdx;
    }
```

Here's my code for saving file:

```
String taString = Integer.toString(a)+","+Float.toString(b)+","+Double.toString(maxVal);
writeToFile(taString);
```

and this the writeToFile function :

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles");
        directory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(directory, "mysdfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

then when I'm open my file (msydfile.txt) its just contains a,b,contour area (like : 15, 4.55, 8418) ..But i want to save others contour area like sequential data.

Hopefully, someone has some experience in this. Thanks..

Comment: do you want to append data to your file?

Comment: @MartinFrank of course yes, i want to save my contour area Log in my file..

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: thanks @ZdaR its very helpful :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to append your data you have to tell the `OutputStream` to do so:

```
boolean append = true;
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
```

see [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) for further explanation.